# How to retrieve bigger int from two halves?

Tags: go

Below is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type BiggerInt struct {
    Upper int64
    Lower int64
}

const (
    bigger    = 9223372036854775808543522345
    divisor64 = 1 << 64
)

func main() {
    var x BiggerInt
    x.Upper = bigger / divisor64
    x.Lower = bigger % divisor64
    fmt.Println(x.Lower + (x.Upper * int64(math.Pow(2, 64)))) // expecting 9223372036854775808543522345, got: 543522345
}
```

---

How to retrieve bigger int from `x.Lower` & `x.Upper`?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting here? You can’t retrieve `9223372036854775808543522345` from an `int64`. If `BiggerInt` is a 128 bit value, then the `BiggerInt` value is the value you want already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note that `const` numbers are untyped - and will have type applied based on context.

```
const (
    bigger    = 9223372036854775808543522345
    divisor64 = 1 << 64
)
```

Neither of these numbers fit into `go`'s largest `int64` integer type, however the following math:

```
var x BiggerInt
x.Upper = bigger / divisor64  // resolved at compile-time ...
x.Lower = bigger % divisor64  // ... so will fit into `int64`
```

skirts any overflow issues, since the assignment values are resolved at compile time and do fit in `int64` types.

Trying to reconstitute this into the original (untyped `bigger`) is not possible with any of the base `go` types (there is no `int128`). So, instead, use the standard library's `math/big` package:

```
import "math/big"

t := big.NewInt(upper)
t.Lsh(t, 64)
t.Add(t, big.NewInt(lower))

fmt.Println(t) // 9223372036854775808543522345
```

https://go.dev/play/p/bHTOssconQa

Comment: Do I need to store value in `big.NewInt()` ? Why `fmt.Println()` does not print the value of expression, in my code?

Comment: Yes, there's no native `go` type to store a result that big - `math/big` uses structs to store arbitrary precision. Your original expression will not work as it tries to fit the result into an `int64`. Even [this operand is incorrect](https://go.dev/play/p/9g-P4A_dpfk).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are expecting. But in case that you don't know, the [math/big](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big) package implements arbitrary-precision arithmetic (big numbers).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

type BiggerInt struct {
    Upper int64
    Lower int64
}

const (
    bigger    = 9223372036854775808543522345
    divisor64 = 1 << 64
)

func main() {
    var x BiggerInt
    x.Upper = bigger / divisor64
    x.Lower = bigger % divisor64

    result := &big.Int{}
    result.Lsh(big.NewInt(x.Upper), 64)
    result.Add(result, big.NewInt(x.Lower))
    fmt.Println(result)
    // output:
    //  9223372036854775808543522345
}
```